# Magento 2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: magento2, cors

I tried

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

and tried for js cross orign from htaccess

`<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>` in the .htaccess. but I still have the Cors error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: are you setting up Magento with Nginx ?

Comment: I face same issue. Can you please help me for sort it out ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the cross-origin in `app/etc/env.php` by changing the following parameter.

```
  'x-frame-options' => 'CROSS-ORIGIN',
```

after changing flush your magento cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you @Rizwan but still the same error

Comment: Can you add your error in question.

Comment: I am also getting same error.

Comment: @RizwanKhan After update still getting the issue, could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/317950/57334

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site config file for example

nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/localmagento.com.conf

and add

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/
     ServerName localmagento.com
     ServerAlias www.localmagento.com
     <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and use a2enmod headers and then restart server.