# How to setup Access_Control_Allow_origin & From origin blocked by CORS in Nginx for Mageno 2 multi-Website store?

Tags: magento2.3.4, server-setup, localhost

My main website store URL: **test.website.in**

Second website store URL : **grocery.website.in**

Initially, i developed multi-website in the localhost, and its working also but after move to live server main website working but second website store not working.

[image]

.htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Host grocery.website.in* MAGE_RUN_CODE=grocery
SetEnvIf Host grocery.website.in* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Note : Followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/charlottes-digital-web/enabling-cors-on-a-magento-2-site-using-an-nginx-server-481c8931f8b2) still facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content->Design->configurations

Click on edit link against your website.

apply a different them for each website.
[image]

now run these commands.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Yes, i set that before still getting the same issue and run commands what you mentioned https://snipboard.io/aHI6YF.jpg

Answer (score 0):

set the cross-origin in app/etc/env.php by changing the following parameter.

```
'x-frame-options' => 'CROSS-ORIGIN',
```

after changing flush your magento cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Comment: After set 'x-frame-options' => 'CROSS-ORIGIN',  getting error => Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up CSP in your website. Check this [Magento CSP doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html)

Create **csp_whitelist.xml** in your module loading the second website inside **etc** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="your-test-website" type="host">test.website.in</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```